# design issue (concerning entering other items in the drop down list)

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, drop-down-menu, usability

Q:

I have the following question about an interface issue.

I have a drop down list contains a list of items . Sometimes ,the user needs to select an item not exist in this drop down list(others).I wanna the user to enter his item and added to the list. What is the best practice to do this from interface(point of view).(usability).and(How to validate the user entry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user selects the `Other` option from the dropdownlist, you can provide the `textbox` to the user that use will be able to enter a new entry. When the user presses OK, after defining the value, you can check the value in the DB, whether this exist or not, if not existed, you can add the value to DB.

I hope, I am able to explain the idea.

**Edit:** Referring to your comment, it will be like..

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = DataSource;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "TextField";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ValueField"
DropDownList1.DataBind();

// Now add the other option, it will be added in the last
DropDownList1.Items.Add("Other");
```

Comment: Then how to make the `other` option is last item every time?

Comment: Thanks a lot. this what i wanna to do.

Answer (score 1):

the best option would be, allow other option in list box when user selects this option add text box dynamically via javascript and once user answers it validate via ajax at server side and then add it to your options.